# Группировка SQL с выводом значений из других столбцов, соответствующих MAX()

Tags: sql, group-by

есть таблица

| person_id | fullname | test_id | date_test | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Vasiliy | 123 | 21.02.2021 | 100 |
| 01 | Vasiliy | 123 | 13.01.2022 | 85 |
| 01 | Vasiliy | 123 | 30.05.2021 | 75 |
| 01 | Vasiliy | 123 | 23.03.2021 | NULL |

Мне надо сгруппировать `GROUP BY` по `person_id` при этом мне надо, чтобы группировалась информация по максимальному score. При этом в SELECT должны отображаться значения из столбцов fullname, test_id, date_test, соответствующие максимальному score. Т.е. в данном случае мне нужен вывод результата:

| person_id | fullname | test_id | date_test | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Vasiliy | 123 | 21.02.2021 | 100 |

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести значения, соответствующие максимальному score

Comment: *есть таблица* Неплохо было бы показать её структуру. Если в таблице нет никаких уникальных ограничений, то задача может оказаться и нерешаемой - у одного person две записи с одинаковым максимальным score и разными date_test.

Answer (score 1):

вариант без группировки (MS SQL):

```
declare @t table (person_id varchar(2), fullname varchar(50),   test_id int, date_test datetime,    score int);
insert into @t (person_id, fullname, test_id, date_test, score)
values
('01',  'Vasiliy',  123, '20210221',    100),
('01',  'Vasiliy',  123, '20220113',85),
('01',  'Vasiliy',  123, '20210530',75),
('01',  'Vasiliy',  123, '20210323',NULL),
('02',  'Ivan', 123, '20220323',10),
('02',  'Ivan', 123, '20220207',50);

WITH m as
    (select person_id, fullname, test_id, date_test, score,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by person_id order by score DESC)
    from @t)
select person_id, fullname, test_id, date_test, score from m where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Score = (SELECT MAX(Score) FROM table)
```

В подзапросе "SELECT MAX(Score) FROM table" мы выбираем максимальный Score, затем, в основном запросе, мы фильтруем с помощью WHERE те строки, в которых Score является максимальным для этой таблицы.